# Ошибка при инициализации owlCarousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я вставил owlCarousel на свой сайт и все работает классно, но как убрать ошибку в консоли, а именно:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:135)
    at l (jquery.js:2)
    at c (jquery.js:2)
```

Которая появляется на страницах где самой карусели нет. Хотел бы все оставить в одном файле js. А не создавать отдельный для конкретного случая.

Answer (score 1):

Перед инициализацией карусели, сначало проверте, есть ли она на странице

```
if($('div').is('.owlCarousel')) {
//инициализация карусели
}
else { 
//действие, если карусели нет. Блок else можно вообще убрать, если вам он не нужен
}
```

Более легковесное решение

```
if ($('.owlCarousel').length > 0) {
   //инициализация карусели
}
```

Comment: Если добавить такой вариант, то карусель пропадает на странице где она есть.

Comment: вы вместо .owlCarousel напишите тот клас или ИД к которому вы привязываете карусель

Comment: так к нему и привязываю:)

Comment: чтобы что-то подсказать, необходимо видеть как вы инициализируете карусель (рабочий вариант), и что вы пытаетесь сделать... а так гадание на кофейной гуще...